# How can i add a Combobox selection to a datagrid

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid which is bound to my ObservableCollection.
Each column is bound to property of the class wellenelement.
Now i would like to convert the column "Art" to a combobox column, where the user can choose from 3 different options.
How can i create these 3 Combobox items and add it to the datagrid?

````xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >

</DataGrid>
```xaml

```c#
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Wellenelement> Welle1;

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Welle1 = new ObservableCollection<Wellenelement>();
            dataGrid1.DataContext = Welle1;

        }
    }
```c#


```c#

public class Wellenelement      
{ 
        public string Art { get; set; }
        public string UK { get; set; }
        public string DA { get; set; }
        public string DI { get; set; }       
}

```c#
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridComboBoxColumn Using the AutoGeneratingColumn Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116337/datagridcomboboxcolumn-using-the-autogeneratingcolumn-event) (note that instead of using AutoGeneratingColumn Event, you might perhaps choose to disable _AutoGenerateColumns_ and explicitly define the columns in the DataGrid XAML)

Comment: Additionally to the linked duplicate, note that you need some collection of "things" (strings in your case, because `Art` is a string) the comboboxes should offer you for selection. Currently, in your code example above, there is no such collection of combobox items in sight...

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same for each item you can add a collection to the viewmodel and add it as a resource to your view. Then you can set the resource as the itemssource for the DataGridComboBoxColumn.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Wellenelements = new ObservableCollection<Wellenelement>()
        {
            new Wellenelement()
            {
                UK = "uk1",
                DA = "da1",
                DI = "di1"
            },
            new Wellenelement()
            {
                UK = "uk2",
                DA = "da2",
                DI = "di2"
            },
        };

        ArtTypes = new List<string>()
        {
            "new art","old art", "good art","bad art"
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Wellenelement> Wellenelements { get; set; }

    public List<string> ArtTypes { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Viewmodels"
        ...>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myCollection" Source="{Binding ArtTypes}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>


        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Wellenelements}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollection}}"
                                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Art, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Header="Art Combo column"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Art}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    Header="Selected Art Type"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UK}"
                                    Header="UK"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DA}"
                                    Header="DA"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DI}"
                                    Header="DI"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Wellenelement class:

```
public class Wellenelement : ObservableObject
{
    public string UK { get; set; }
    public string DA { get; set; }
    public string DI { get; set; }


    private string _art;
    public string Art
    {
        get { return _art; }
        set
        {
            _art = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Art));
        }
    }
}
```